# What to do with cross-posted questions answered on another site?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

Here is a [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/pairwise-independent-gaussians) cross-posted to MO and answered [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46180/how-to-sample-pairwise-independent-gaussians). The OP has accepted the answer on MO.

Should we ask OP to post an answer with a link to the answer on the other site (alternatively copy the answer from the other site) and accept it so the question does not remain unanswered on cstheory?

A previous [case](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/complexity-of-finding-the-eigendecomposition-of-a-matrix) of the situation where another suer has posted an answer with linking to the answer on MO.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be for someone/anyone to post a CW answer that references/copies the answer from the other site.  This avoids whatever issues people have about free rep points.  (What's mysterious to me is whether accepting a CW answer gives the answerer points -- a test of this might be worthwhile.)

Comment: I don't think CW answers contribute any points to the poster, but they can contribute badges (if for example a CW answer gets 10 votes and is accepted, it's eligible for an Enlightened badge). This is a sufficiently minor issue that I don't think it's a problem, so overall I like your suggestion if we feel we want to go your (and Jukka's) route.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with Suresh. I think we should always be a bit selfish and think what is best for *our* site, *our* users, and people who find *our* site by googling.

I think it would be better for us if someone (OP or anyone else) posted an answer here, and then the OP accepted the answer. The answer could be, e.g., a link to MO and a short summary of the answer there, or a full copy-paste if it makes sense. The question should be left open.

This way *our* users will get some useful information, too. People who don't actively follow the question but every now and then check the front page will notice that this question has now some answers. People who use search engines will get useful information through our site more quickly; accepted answers are easy to find while comments are easy to miss. Our users can write additional answers and provide more information. And in general, an on-topic question with an accepted answer looks much more attractive than a question that was closed (also in our statistics...).

Comment: I don't know how much of a problem this to warrant a special solution to help googling. I'd be more inclined to edit the original post itself (not even the comments, as I originally sugested) and add a link to the answer. But I'm not wedded to the idea either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better for the OP to add a comment on the post here saying that the post has been answered, and then someone can flag it for closing.

Comment: Why should we close the post here? Matt Hastings (http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/quantum-pcp-and-hardness-of-simulation/3146#3146) and I (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45106/quantum-pcp-theorem/45167#45167) both answered the same question here and on MathOverflow, and the answers don't duplicate each other. We don't close questions after getting a good answer here, so why should we close questions after there's a good answer on another site? It's not quite the same as having a duplicate question on the same site.

Comment: But there should at least be some notification that the question has been answered ? maybe closing is too draconian ?

Comment: Somebody should definitely put up notification that the question has been answered. I don't know whose responsibility this should be. But another reason to leave it open on both sites is that on, say, mathoverflow, you may get math-oriented answers while here, you may get tcs-oriented answers. They tend to be different.